# Плагин для vs code. Просмотр usage'ей переменной или функции

Tags: javascript, php, java, visual-studio-code

есть возможность посмотреть все места где используется функция/переменная в проекте.

Наподобие ctrl + ЛКМ ( по названию ) в IDEA

Языки: js, java , PHP

Comment: Какой плагин нужен - зависит от языка.

Comment: Для следующих: Js, java , php

Comment: А чего полноценную IDE не используете? Там подобные вещи "из коробки".
PHP storm тот же

Comment: Пока нет возможности платить за него

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Моя проблема решилась плагином - php intellisense.